# What causes cells to inactivate one X-chromosome?

Tags: genetics, cell-biology, dna, chromosome, genomes

Normally, when a cell has two X-chromosomes (female genome), one is randomly inactivated. How does the cell detect that there are two X-chromosomes in the first place?

Is there some kind of protein that's coded in the X-chromosome, such that having two X's increases the protein concentration and a dosage effect causes one to become inactivated? I can't find any information about it in my textbook, nor on Google. A citation would be appreciated - especially for peer-reviewed research.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Even a male cell can count the number of X chromosomes. (Lee et al. 1996; Cell 86: 83-84)

When X inactivation is getting started the two chromosomes "kiss" - a process that lasts for a couple of hours (first shown by Jeannie Lee in 1996). The physical contact between two X chromosomes is over a small fraction of the chromosome but it's essential for triggering inactivation. (Xu et al. 2006: Science 311: 1149-52)

If it doesn't happen then the X chromosome assumes it's alone which would mean that Xist never gets switched on and inactivation never happens (a key stage in chromosome counting).

> [Chromosome counting](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27504142) is a process in which cells determine somehow
>   their intrinsic chromosome number(s). The best-studied cellular
>   mechanism that involves chromosome counting is 'chromosome-kissing'
>   and X-chromosome inactivation (XCI) mechanism. It is necessary for the
>   well-known dosage compensation between the genders in mammals to
>   balance the number of active X-chromosomes (Xa) with regard to diploid
>   set of autosomes. At the onset of XCI, two X-chromosomes are coming in
>   close proximity and pair physically by a specific segment denominated
>   X-pairing region (Xpr) that involves the SLC16A2 gene.

Take a look at [Xist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XIST) and [Tsix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsix). Some more papers worth taking a look at:
[Xist regulation and function eXplored](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3132428/)
Mechanism of regulation of ‘[chromosome kissing](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4470286/)’ induced by Fob1 and its physiological significance

Comment: Please note that this only applies to placental mammals. Drosophila, for example, has a different method for compensating for the two copies of the XX chromosome in females.